# How to set in 3d plot the axis values to specific values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to generate a heatcube. The axis are specific values for 3 different parameters and the actual value of a point `(x,y,z)` is a goodness of fit value. That means `(x,y,z)` should be read as **categorical** variables. However, I struggle to get the axis on the right scale so that it only considers the given values to be plotted and not a continuum of points

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    
lam = [0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 10]
alpha = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2]
delta = [0, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 10]
    
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(lam, alpha, delta)
    
c = np.random.randn(len(lam), len(alpha), len(delta))
ax.scatter(X,Y,Z, c=c,cmap="brg")
plt.show()
```

which gives a misleading picture:

[image]

As one can see the plot has by far too large spaces on the different axis. I would like to have only points shown the actual values of `lam`, `alpha`, `delta` like in this plot

[Matplotlib scatter 3d colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192679/matplotlib-scatter-3d-colors)

Comment: `I want to generate a headcube` - could you be more specific? its unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal see my updated question. At the end, i have a specific grid for certain x, y and z values. Each of these values correspond to a hyperparameter in a model. The value (generated by random normal distribution in this case) is a goodness of fit score. So for x=0.000001, y=0.001 and z=0 I have a score. however for example for z=6 there no score which gives a too large spae in the plot above

Comment: at the end the issue is that X,Y and Z should be categorical variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `set_{}ticks` for ax:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

lam = [0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 10]
alpha = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2]
delta = [0, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 10]

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(lam, alpha, delta)

c = np.random.randn(len(lam), len(alpha), len(delta))
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=c, cmap="brg",)
ax.set_xticks(lam)
ax.set_yticks(alpha)
ax.set_zticks(delta)
plt.show()
```

It does not look good though, because you have no logarithmic scale:
[image]

Better solution (maybe thats what you wanted after all) is to make meshgrid of indices and substitute labels of ticks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

lam = [0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 10]
alpha = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2]
delta = [0, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 10]

# X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(lam, alpha, delta)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(len(lam)), np.arange(len(alpha)), np.arange(len(delta)))

c = np.random.randn(len(lam), len(alpha), len(delta))
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=c, cmap="brg",)
ax.set_xticklabels(lam)
ax.set_yticklabels(alpha)
ax.set_zticklabels(delta)
plt.show()
```

[image]