# How to correctly space room between ticks and labels and center title

Tags: matplotlib

Following up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72507068/how-to-set-in-3d-plot-the-axis-values-to-specific-values), I would like to know two things. How can I increase the spacing between the ticklabels and axis labels? How can I increase the point size? Just setting `s=3` seems not to work. And lastly, why is the title in a such a weird position and not centered on top?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

lam = [0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 10]
alpha = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2]
delta = [0, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 10]

# X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(lam, alpha, delta)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(len(lam)), np.arange(len(alpha)), np.arange(len(delta)))

c = np.random.randn(len(lam), len(alpha), len(delta))
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=c, cmap="brg",)
ax.set_xticklabels(lam)
ax.set_yticklabels(alpha)
ax.set_zticklabels(delta)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

To shift the ticks off the axis, add a pad value in the ticks parameter. If it overlaps with an axis label, add a pad value to the axis label as well. Also, the location of the title, it's not in your code, but I added it. The default is center, but I intentionally set it to the left. If this is not satisfactory, you can annotate it with `ax.text()`. Finally, the marker size does not change, it is affected by the graph size, so set the graph size larger.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12)) # update
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

lam = [0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 10]
alpha = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2]
delta = [0, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 1, 10]

# X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(lam, alpha, delta)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(len(lam)), np.arange(len(alpha)), np.arange(len(delta)))

c = np.random.randn(len(lam), len(alpha), len(delta))
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=c, cmap="brg", s=350)
ax.set_xticklabels(lam)
ax.set_yticklabels(alpha)
ax.set_zticklabels(delta)

# update    
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', pad=8)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\lambda$', labelpad=10)
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\alpha$', labelpad=10)
ax.set_zlabel(r'$\delta$', labelpad=10)

ax.set_title(r'$Heatcube\ for\ \lambda, \alpha, \delta$', fontsize=16, loc='left')

plt.show()
```

[image]